# Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc32dc066d0' when starting a audio session

Tags: ios, object

```
- (IBAction)record:(id)sender {
    if (player.playing) {
        [player stop];
    }

    if (!recorder.recording) {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

        NSError *error = nil;

        [session setActive:YES error:&error];

        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error finding Name1: %@",error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"No error");
        }

        [recorder record];
        [recordButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [recorder pause];
        [recordButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [stopButton setEnabled:YES];
    [playButton setEnabled:NO];

}
```

The above code is an action linked to a button `Record` in the main storyboard. I am trying to start an audio session and start recording when the user taps the `Record` button. But whenever I start the application in the **simulator** and then click the `Record` button, I got the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController recordButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa4106072e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ca1b1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bc67031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ca9c784 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010d0c66db -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c99d898 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c99d278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ce993e8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d0147a4 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d014ac1 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d013a09 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 580
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010cf0e0bf -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010cf0f7c1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4086
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010ceb3310 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d7f46af __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2796
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d7f72c4 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5949
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c9bdbb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c9a24af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c9a1a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c9a130b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011373fa73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010ce98057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    21  Demo                                0x000000010b36504f main + 111
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110478955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What is wrong here? I handle the only error may occur in this action method. Don't understand..

Comment: Did you change the name of your function from `recordButton` to `record` after hooking up the outlet in interface builder?  Just delete the connection and connect it again.

Comment: @dan The function is called `record` and the outlet is called `recordButton`. What do you mean by changing the name of the function from `recordButton` to `record`? I am little confused.

Comment: Read the error message.  Your button is trying to call `-[ViewController recordButton:]` when tapped, which means you connected the button action to a method that looked like `- (IBAction)recordButton:(id)sender` which no longer exists.  It doesn't matter anyway, just delete the button action connection in the interface builder and connect it again.